# XCode 5 and iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, xcode4.6, ios6.1

I'm working on an iOS app that I wrote with Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.x. Now that XCode 5 has been released alongside with iOS 7, I wanted to support both iOS 6.x and iOS 7.x by using either XCode 4.6 or XCode 5. What is the best way to approach this?. Can I just toggle between iOS 6.x SDK and iOS 7.x SDK from within XCode 4.6 or do I have to upgrade to XCode 5 to accomplish this?.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode 4.6 will not support iOS 7 by any means. You will only be able to build iOS 6 apps that will run on iOS 7, but you will not be able to use new iOS 7 SDS features.

If you want to support iOS 7 features, you need to use Xcode 5. This might also cause some visual issues in your app.

My suggestion is to migrate to Xcode 5 and then check that everything is ok in your app, or do the required changes so that it works fine on iOS 7.

In any case, you can safely go back to Xcode 4 from Xcode 5, if you see that anything does not work out as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I read in some articles that you can force XCode 5 to toggle between iOS 6 SDK and iOS 7 SDK. Is it possible?

Comment: You can try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424920/how-to-point-xcode-to-my-10-6-sdk-so-it-can-be-used-as-a-base-sdk/11424966, which worked on previous Xcode versions. But I think this is not supported in any way, so cannot guarantee that all will be fine. In my case, I have a couple of apps that I will not update to iOS7, so to make things easy I will stick to Xcode 4.6 for both.

Comment: Since iOS 7 s already out, I'm not sure whether Apple will approve my app built against iOS 6.x when I'm requesting for approval next month.

Comment: I see your point. As I said, switching to Xcode 5 and use it to support iOS 7 and below should be no big deal. What you need is specifying the "Deployment iOS version" in info.plist file and you will make your app (potentially) work on older versions of iOS.

Comment: Thanks. If it is that easy, why I'm seeing articles telling how to override XCode5 to switch between iOS versions like this one: http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/09/how-to-support-old-ios-sdks-in-xcode-5/