# How to use iPhone sdk 6.1 in Xcode5?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, sdk, rubymotion

I recently downloaded XCode 5 and upgraded my os. Now my setup is:

OSX Version: 10.8.5

XCode Version: 5

I opened Xcode -> Preferences and installed iOS 6.1 simulator and iOS 5.1 simulator, however, I don't see them under: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`

I only see `iPhoneOS7.0.sdk` in that directory

For some of my apps I want to use 6.1 so I get this error:

> ERROR! Can't locate iPhoneOS SDK 6.1 at
>   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk'

How can I get the SDK 6.1 from XCode 5?

I can't find the iphoneos SDK 6.1 in this search either: https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=iphoneos%2Bsdk

Comment: you should checkout at this path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk"

Comment: I have this set in my rubymotion project's Rakefile: `app.sdk_version = "6.1"` which is by default searching in a specified folder. How can I change it? Guess I can ask a separate question for that..

Answer (score 1):

You can build your app against the iOS 7 SDK with a deployment target of iOS 6, iOS 5, or even 4.3. That's what Apple expects you to do.

If you need to build against the iOS 6.1 SDK, I think your only option is to copy the SDK from Xcode 4.6.3 into Xcode 5. I found a link here on SO that showed how to do it. What you do is to open Xcode 4.3 (right click, show package contents) Then navigate to:

/Applications/Xcode 4.6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

Copy the folder iPhoneOS6.1.sdk and paste it into the same path inside the Xcode 5 app.

You can also create a simlink inside Xcode 5 that points to the SDK inside Xcode 4.6.3 (or some other location on your system.)

Look at the [original SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424920/how-to-point-xcode-to-my-10-6-sdk-so-it-can-be-used-as-a-base-sdk/11424966) for info on that.

Comment: I'm using ruby motion to build my app. Even when I change the sdk_version to 6, it can't find the 6 SDK..

Answer (score 0):

You can check this from xcode.

If you want to see you app in ios 6 or latter versions then

go in File inspector and change view as a option into ios 6.0 and earlier . please check this image.

[image]

Comment: Did you download both simulators in Xcode 5?