# Target OS X 10.7+ on Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode5, osx-lion

I've been trying to build an app that supports 10.7+ using Xcode 5 on 10.9.  I can get 10.8+ working but have not succeeded in getting 10.7 to work.

I've tried the following:

- disabled base internationalization (i think)
- turned off autolayout in my xib
- set 10.7+ as the target for my xib
- copied in the 10.6 and 10.7 SDKs from 4.3.3 into my Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platforms/Developers/SDKs folder
- set deployment target to 10.7
- set by base sdks to 10.7

When I do the above (mainly the deployment target and base SDKs) I can't run on 10.9.  I get the following error message.

Xcode cannot run using the selected destination.

This seems exceptionally difficult.  What am I missing?  What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message suggests you are trying to run 64-bit code on a 32-bit destination. Having reproduced your steps, I see this problem intermittently, but if I clean and re-run it, it works.

Do make sure that you've selected a 64-bit destination ("My Mac 64-bit") and that you're building for 64-bit Intel (and not "Universal" for instance). I do suspect there's an Xcode bug in here since I'm seeing it fail and then succeed if I clean between, but this is not a supported configuration and Apple's not going to help you (i.e. a radar is probably a waste of time).

BTW: [I build for 10.5 every day with Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424920/how-to-point-xcode-to-my-10-6-sdk-so-it-can-be-used-as-a-base-sdk/11424966) without any problems, but I'm explicitly building for 32-bit only and so am probably not bumping into this problem.

Comment: Thank you Rob!  Just the tip that i'm on the right path helps...i'll keep at it.