# Xcode 6 delete iOS 7 sdk... how can I get it again?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

Does anyone knows where to download iOS 7 SDK? Xcode 6 deleted on it's automatic updated.

Comment: You can download it from the Xcode preference dialog on the download tab.

Comment: I can only download iOS 7 simulator and not the SDK

Comment: did you try with some links below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045307/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-7-sdk-on-xcode-6

Comment: Why do you need to the 7 SDK, just compile with the 8 SDK and set the deployment target to 7.

Comment: Or if you really need to, download Xcode 5 and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 6 does not pack the iOS 7 SDK but the iOS 8 SDK. There is [a way to make Xcode 6 work with the iOS 7 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045307/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-7-sdk-on-xcode-6), as @David commented.

But if all you want is to support iOS 7 & iOS 8, all you need is to set your project's minimum target to iOS 7. If you want to test on the iOS 7 Simulator, you can download it it the Downloads section of Xcode's Preferences window.

Comment: There IS a way to make Xcode 6 recognise the iOS 7 SDK, as this answer clearly shows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045307/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-7-sdk-on-xcode-6

Comment: @David : sorry about the imprecision, I edited my post to include your reference.

Comment: No worries. Changed my down vote to an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to say the `iOS7 simulator`: this can be downloaded within the `Downloads` section of XCode preferences no need to download a previous version of `XCode`. You simply need then to set your deployment target to iOS7 within your project setting (`General Section`).