# Xcode 6 doesn't show iOS 7.1 simulators

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have the Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with all iOS 8 simulators. I have also downloaded the iOS 7.1 simulators.

I am developing an app for iOS 8 and iOS 7.

The problem I encounter is that Xcode 6 doesn't show the iOS 7.1 simulators in the devices menu. At some point it did show them but on my newly created Xcode 6 project it does not.

I was looking at some stackoverflow solutions.I have addded the iOS 7.1 simulators  Window - Devices - SIMULATORS. They are also checked with "Show in the Run Destionations Menu",however they are not shown.

I found a workaround by setting the Project and Target Deployment Target to 7.1. However, this is a stupid solution since for every test I need to manually switch them forth and back 7.1-8.0

This is my first ipad app and it worked perfectly under Xcode 5.1.1. iOS 7 and iOS 8 (CREATED UNDER Xcode 5.1.1.). Now I have created a project in Xcode 6.0.1. and the project doesn't have the simulators showing correctly and 95% of the app doesn't work.

I am new to iOS development but I suppose that this is a bug, but I am unsure. Please help.

Comment: How is it a problem. If you need to support an older version of the is that's what you set the deployment target to.

Comment: Why do you have to switch the deployment target between 7.1 and 8.0. The app will work perfectly in both 7.1 and 8.0 if you have the target set to 7.1

Comment: So my deployment target is not the latest iOS version but the lowest on which the app is supposed to work? If I need to support iOS 7.1 then this is my deployment target? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: You can install iOS7 simulator with the help of this post [Is it possible to install iOS 7 SDK on Xcode 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045307/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-7-sdk-on-xcode-6). It works for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The deployment target is the minimum OS version you intend to support.

As you stated, you need to set the deployment target to 7.1 in order to see the 7.1 simulators.  If your deployment target is 8.0, the 7.1 simulators will not be available in the run destinations menu.  This is the correct behavior because you can't run on iOS 7.1 if your deployment target is 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

I already had deployment target 7.0 and simulator still wasn't available for 7.1.

I fixed the issue though by going into Xcode preferences, selected Downloads and re-downled the missing 7.1 simulators under 'Components'. Although I previously had 7.1 simulator, the Xcode 6 upgrade had seemed to remove them.

[image]

Comment: I did this step before I changed the deployment target. This is true, Xcode does remove the previous version of simulator upon update. +1 for pointing it out. I am not alone out there with Xcode behaving awkward :)

Comment: This actually fixed the issue I was having; the accepted answer didn't. Thanks!