# Using iPhoneSimulator 8.4 SDK in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I've tried the method mentioned here,

[How to point Xcode to an old SDK so it can be used as a "Base SDK"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424920/how-to-point-xcode-to-an-old-sdk-so-it-can-be-used-as-a-base-sdk)

I downloaded Xcode 6.4 and located 8.4 SDK for iphone simulator.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
ln -s /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/
```

Then I modified `MinimumSDKVersion` here in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Info.plist`

[image]

Now I restart Xcode, the SDK for iPhone simulator was not present.

[image]

If I click on `others` and add `iphonesos8.4` it says `iphoneos8.4 (sdk not found`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform Info.plist, that way Xcode can pick up that 8.4 SDK and link against it.  Then you should be able to run against the iPhone 8.4 simulator.  If that still doesn't work, then forget the symbolic link and just copy the entire source SDK Folder and rename it iPhoneOS8.4.sdk